# Which is the felica protocol to permit a java cardTerminal to connect to a card

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard

I am working on Felica Tag with the ACR Reader 122.

The following code that works to connect to all other type of nfc tag is not working for Felica Tag

```
Card card = terminal.connect("*");
```

I get the following exception :

> javax.smartcardio.CardException: connect() failed     at
>   sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.connect(TerminalImpl.java:67)
>   Caused by: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException:
>   SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD    at
>   sun.security.smartcardio.PCSC.SCardConnect(Native Method)     at
>   sun.security.smartcardio.CardImpl.(CardImpl.java:65)    at
>   sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.connect(TerminalImpl.java:61)

It seems Felica tag has is own protocol but I can't find the transmission protocol name.

Does any one knwows how to connect to a felica card with the java card library ?

(Acr Reader 122 supports this kind of tag)

******* Edit **********

More strange
If I do something really ugly like acquiring a "channel" from an topaz tag, and then
using this channel to communicate with my Felica Tag, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Simple.

Not all ACR 122 is compatible with Felica Lite.

ACR122 PCSC version. e.g. FW20X, FW40X are not.

The recommanded version to work with felica lite tag is ACR122 PCSC e.g. FW10X

Answer (score 0):

The package `javax.smartcardio` implements [JSR 268](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=268). This is meant for use with ISO 7816-4 cards and is not compatible at all with FeliCa cards.

Comment: For me, the ACR122 emulates the nfc tag as a javaCard to permit to communicate with the nfc tag. I don't send directly the "tag command" but I encapsulate my command to special APDU command for "ACR 122". I don't get any trouble to connect to topaz or mifare nfc tag that are under the protocol-ISO/IEC 14443-3A.

Comment: @Yop that's pretty specific to the reader, so you may want to ask them. Otherwise I would simply try "T=0" or "T=1
 or of course "T=CL".